# Опера, мозила и хром не отображают кириллицу

Tags: html

То есть в коде всё выглядит нормально, а браузезы отображают билиберду. Charset стоит на utf8.

Comment: А строка передаётся в utf8? Покажите минимальный пример.

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: @Василий а кодировка файла - utf-8?

Comment: Поменял, помогло, спасибо!

Comment: @Василий поменял кодировку файла? Ну тогда я вынесу это в ответ.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

- заголовок `Content-Type`
- а при его отсутствии - тэг `<meta charset="utf-8">`
- или его старый аналог `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

задают кодировку, в которой браузер должен отобразить содержимое.

Но при этом содержимое html-файла должно само по себе быть в UTF-8. Иначе браузер покажет какой-нибудь CP1252 как UTF-8 и получится билиберда.

Answer (score 0):

Поменяй кодирвку файла .html и все будет норм.
Например в Notepad++ вкладка Кодировки- Преобразовать в UTF-8.

Answer (score -3):

*Никакие HTML теги* на кодировку не влияют.
Кодировка страницы задается только **НТТР заголовком** `Content-type`.
Надо настраивать сервер, чтобы отдавал правильный заголовок.

Отдаваемый сервером заголовок можно посмтореть в консоли разработчика во вкладке "Сеть"

Comment: Ну, насчёт «задаётся только» — это приукрашивает действительность. _Должна задаваться_.